# JavaScript condition always fails

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage

In the below code, the `if` statement always fails. New to `JavaScript`, couldn't figure out.

I believe the code is self explanatory. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (localStorage.user_name === null || localStorage.user_name === 'undefined') {
    registerUser(userName);
} else {
    login(localStorage.user_name);  // Gets executed always... Even if there is no user_name in localStorage.
}
```

Comment: `null ` and `undefined` are falsy. You needn't check them explicitly. Try with - `if (localStorage.user_name) { ..// code }`

Comment: I think you can use this -> http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: Nice reference.

Comment: btw `undefined` is not a string, if you would to check if some is undefined you should use

`typeof localStorage.user_name === 'undefined'`

Comment: `===` is very specific comparison. Is failing because `localStorage.user_name` is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your second condition. Since you're using `===`, and comparing with `'undefined'` which is a string, instead of `undefined`, it returns false. So, you need `localStorage === undefined`, as in

```
if (localStorage.user_name === null || localStorage.user_name === undefined)
```

Or, need to use `typeof` which returns `String`. But there's a better way

```
if(!localStorage.user_name){

}
```

Comment: NO, using == is not right way....it is comparing like `undefined=='undefined'`...which is not true.

Comment: @GokulNath its not wrong as it is being typecasted.

Comment: @Vijay nope. It's right. You need to look up on that for why.

Comment: I got it...it is working because of first condition. `undefined==null` is true while `undefined===null` is false.